# How to Activate Button After you Type Number in Input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I dont want the button to be clickable until the user types in a number into the input.

Before the user types in the number I want the button to be a little bit faded so maybe have the opacity about 75%.

After the user types in a number then I want the opacity to be 100% and then the user can click the button.

Here is an example of what I want please see the screenshots below.

here is a link to codepen in case you prefer that.
https://codepen.io/rubenjr005/pen/yLJVwze?editors=1100

[image: NOT CLICKABLE BUTTON]

[image: NOW YOU CAN CLICK ON THE BUTTON]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}
.btn.btn-custom {
  margin-right: 2rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.btn.btn-xl {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn.btn-gradient-purple {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #4d31b6 0%, #4d31b6 100%);
}
.btn.btn-gradient-purple:hover, .btn.btn-gradient-purple:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #3023ae 0%, #c96dd8 100%);
}
.btn.btn-gradient-summer {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.btn.btn-gradient-summer:hover, .btn.btn-gradient-summer:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #d9534f 0%, #f0ad4e 100%);
}

.form-row {
margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="form-row">


                                                <div class="form-group col-md" data-toggle="buttons">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="q7_a1" id="q7_a1">
                                                    <label for="bp_sys" style="width:220px;">Top Number
                                                        (Systolic)&nbsp;</label>
                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-md"
                                                        id="bp_sys" min=50 max=300 placeholder="Systolic"
                                                        style="width:200px;display:inline;">
                                                    <div style="width:200px;margin:10px;"></div>
                                                    <label for="bp_dia" style="width:220px;">Bottom Number
                                                        (Diastolic)&nbsp;</label>
                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-md"
                                                        id="bp_dia" min=20 max=200 placeholder="Diastolic"
                                                        style="width:200px;display:inline">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>


<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
   <a href="#" id="hello" class="btn btn-custom btn-xl btn-gradient-summer">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use pointer events to make the button clickable/unclickable.

```
// CSS class to provent clicking
.noClick {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.75%:
}
```

Then just conditionally apply the class when you don't want the element to be clickable.

Comment: The elegance of this solution is admirable, but as a technicality this does not actually prevent the element from being activated. It just makes the object underneath the target of the click instead, which could (but probably wont) cause other issues. None the less, +1 for simplicity. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: thetechnician94 Great Point, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Ah yes, there is an 's' at the end. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to do it (with some little CSS).

In this example, if the input fields are not filled in, the button will appear "greyed out", and the button will not work.

Since links cannot be "disabled", we can work around this by adding an `onclick` attribute (`onclick="return validate()"`). The method `validate()` will return false if the user did not fill in the fields, vice versa.

```js
function validate() {
     if(document.getElementById("bp_sys").value===""||document.getElementById("bp_dia").value==="") { 
            document.getElementById('hello').disabled = true; 
             document.getElementById('hello').style.opacity = "0.5"; 
             return false;
        } else { 
        document.getElementById('hello').style.opacity = "1"; 
            document.getElementById('hello').disabled = false;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}
.btn.btn-custom {
  margin-right: 2rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.btn.btn-xl {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn.btn-gradient-purple {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #4d31b6 0%, #4d31b6 100%);
}
.btn.btn-gradient-purple:hover, .btn.btn-gradient-purple:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #3023ae 0%, #c96dd8 100%);
}
.btn.btn-gradient-summer {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.btn.btn-gradient-summer:hover, .btn.btn-gradient-summer:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #d9534f 0%, #f0ad4e 100%);
}

.form-row {
margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
#hello{
opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="form-row">


                                                <div class="form-group col-md" data-toggle="buttons">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="q7_a1" id="q7_a1">
                                                    <label for="bp_sys" style="width:220px;">Top Number
                                                        (Systolic)&nbsp;</label>
                                                    <input onkeyup="validate()"type="number" class="form-control form-control-md"
                                                        id="bp_sys" min=50 max=300 placeholder="Systolic"
                                                        style="width:200px;display:inline;">
                                                    <div style="width:200px;margin:10px;"></div>
                                                    <label for="bp_dia" style="width:220px;">Bottom Number
                                                        (Diastolic)&nbsp;</label>
                                                    <input onkeyup="validate()"type="number" class="form-control form-control-md"
                                                        id="bp_dia" min=20 max=200 placeholder="Diastolic"
                                                        style="width:200px;display:inline">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>


<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
   <a href="google.com" onclick="return validate()" id="hello" class="btn btn-custom btn-xl btn-gradient-summer">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

You can take it even further with the `cursor:not-allowed`:

```js
function validate() {
     if(document.getElementById("bp_sys").value===""||document.getElementById("bp_dia").value==="") { 
            document.getElementById('hello').disabled = true; 
             document.getElementById('hello').style.opacity = "0.5"; 
             document.getElementById("hello").style.cursor = "not-allowed";
             return false;
        } else { 
        document.getElementById('hello').style.opacity = "1"; 
            document.getElementById('hello').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("hello").style.cursor = "pointer";
            return true;
        }
    }
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}
.btn.btn-custom {
  margin-right: 2rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.btn.btn-xl {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn.btn-gradient-purple {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #4d31b6 0%, #4d31b6 100%);
}
.btn.btn-gradient-purple:hover, .btn.btn-gradient-purple:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #3023ae 0%, #c96dd8 100%);
}
.btn.btn-gradient-summer {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.btn.btn-gradient-summer:hover, .btn.btn-gradient-summer:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #d9534f 0%, #f0ad4e 100%);
}

.form-row {
margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
#hello{
opacity:0.5;
cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="form-row">


                                                <div class="form-group col-md" data-toggle="buttons">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="q7_a1" id="q7_a1">
                                                    <label for="bp_sys" style="width:220px;">Top Number
                                                        (Systolic)&nbsp;</label>
                                                    <input onkeyup="validate()"type="number" class="form-control form-control-md"
                                                        id="bp_sys" min=50 max=300 placeholder="Systolic"
                                                        style="width:200px;display:inline;">
                                                    <div style="width:200px;margin:10px;"></div>
                                                    <label for="bp_dia" style="width:220px;">Bottom Number
                                                        (Diastolic)&nbsp;</label>
                                                    <input onkeyup="validate()"type="number" class="form-control form-control-md"
                                                        id="bp_dia" min=20 max=200 placeholder="Diastolic"
                                                        style="width:200px;display:inline">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>


<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
   <a href="google.com" onclick="return validate()" id="hello" class="btn btn-custom btn-xl btn-gradient-summer">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but his "Continue" button is an anchor, which has no disabled attribute that he can set? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp

Comment: @thetechnician94 It's just in case he decided to use a button. You are completely right.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code correctly, your "Continue" button is just a link. Which presents a problem: **links cannot be disabled** (see [How to disable links](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/)).

What you might be able to do is add an "onChange" property to your number fields and then when the user types in them the function can check to see if their is a number in both fields. If there is set the opacity to 100% (or another appropriate style; background-color maybe?) and set the href of your link. If both are not filled in set the opacity to 75% and *remove the href*.

That means by default your link should have the "disabled" style (which is apparently included in Bootstrap, which I see you are using) and *no href*. Once the user enters data, remove the disabled style and set the href.

Either that or use an actual `<input type='button'/>` and use the .disabled property to actually disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

The logic to activate a button upon a number value in a texbox:

```
<script>
 function buttonFunction () {
  if (document.getElementById("number").value.length > 1) {
   document.getElementById("button").disabled = false; 
    //change opacity using css property here
 } else {
   document.getElementById("button").disabled = true; 
 }
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="number" name="number" oninput="buttonFunction()">
<button id="button" >Click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This only works if OP uses a button element. He is currently using an anchor.